# Will Retrieving The Last Inserted ID From DB risk getting Mix Up If The Traffic Is High?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

In Codeigniter we use

```
* (Method that inserts a new row in the DB ) *
```

Then:

```
last_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

To retrieve the ID of the "lasts created" row in the DB.

What if we have a very high traffic on the application, will it accidentally get the ID of something created by another user?

**The Flow:**

1. Insert a row into the DB
2. Run the insert_id-method to get the "last inserted ID"
3. Use that ID

Is there a risk that another user might have created a new row in-between step #1 & #2?

Or is it "instant" no matter what the traffic is?

If not, how can we best prevent a mixup in-between steps with a high traffic?

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not a problem. The last insert ID is a per-connection value. If another user creates a row, they have a different connections, so it doesn't affect the connection used by the first application.

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a ***per-connection basis***. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column ***by that client***. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no risk, unless you insert another row using the same connection.

In case you want to, just store your first insertion id in a variable:

```
$last_id1 = $this->db->insert_id(); //Pretend its 10
//...Another insertion here...
$last_id2 = $this->db->insert_id(); //Pretend its 13
```

Now output both values:

```
echo "ID1: $last_id1"; //Prints 'ID1: 10'
echo "ID2: $last_id2"; //Prints 'ID2: 13'
```

Now, you will be able to work with the first value in other moment, even if there were other rows inserted